# Coded UI Test Builder cannot be started because the file '' is read-only

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, ui-testing

I have created an **new UIMap** in my project. I was able to work with it day before this error appeared. Now, when I right click on the **new UIMap** in VS (Visual Studio) and Click "Edit With Coded UI Test Builder" option - above error pops up.

I tried starting VS as admin, editing the .uitest file in the project folder (bad practice even if you know what you're doing) and saving it (it allowed me to do this), but still won't let me record using the **new UIMap**.

Additionally the **original UIMap** still works. I am using different names for UIMap if anyone is wondering.

I am using VS2012.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and **A Solution** for it, but not the cause. The properties of UIMaps **.cs** and **.Designer.cs** files were set to read-only. Please do let me know if anyone does find out what causes this and how to prevent this from occuring in the future.

My Solution:

1. Right click on the UIMaps **.cs** and **.Designer.cs** files in the project folder
2. Click on Properties
3. Untick Read-only tickbox

Voilà!

Thanks all.

Comment: Are you using a version control tool?  In particular, are you using TFS, Vault, Perforce or VSS?

Comment: TFS, and I'm a one man team. Do you think it could've locked the files somehow?

Comment: Yes.  Team Foundation Server (in 2010 and older, and using Server Workspaces in 2012) keeps files read-only until you explicitly check them out.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg537361.aspx#tfsc